# What is the purpose of the inline function modifier in HLSL?

Tags: graphics, 3d, shader, inline, hlsl

According to [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-function-syntax),

> [StorageClass is a] modifier that redefines a function declaration. inline is currently the only modifier value. The modifier value must be inline because it is also the default value. **Therefore, a function is inline regardless of whether you specify inline, and all functions in HLSL are inline.**

If all functions in HLSL are inline, why even have the modifier? If the only modifier value is inline, why even have the StorageClass part of the function declaration?